# How to add rapidjson::Document in file

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I need to parse a file, get some data and write them in another file using RapidJson.

Right now I could retrieve values and put them in a document. My only problem is to insert that document in file:

```
FILE * pFile = fopen ("read.json" , "r");

FILE * wFile = fopen ("Test.json" , "w");

if (pFile != NULL)
{
    rapidjson::FileStream is(pFile);
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.ParseStream<0>(is);
    string mMeshID = a.GetString();
    //how to add that document to wfile
    fclose (pFile);
}
```

Is there any way to write a RapidJson::Document in file ?

**EDIT**: the only way I found is:

```
    // Convert JSON document to string
    GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > buffer;
    Writer<GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > > writer(buffer);
    doc.Accept(writer);
    const char* str = buffer.GetString();
    fprintf(wFile, "%s", str);
    fclose(wFile);
```

Comment: the [tutorial.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/source/browse/branches/version0.1x/example/tutorial/tutorial.cpp) does some stringification at the very end, but I can't seem to find any documentation beside the user guide, so this may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: but still not got how to write in file

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I'd wager that FileStream they use to write to stdout could write to other files, too... :)

Comment: Please do you have some code or example

Comment: in the tutorial.cpp I linked, at the very end, they write the document to a `FileStream(stdout)`, `stdout` is a `FILE*`, so just try `FileStream(wFile)`

Answer (score 1):

There is better documentation about [`FileWriteStream`](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_stream.html#FileWriteStream) after this question was asked.

Using `FileWriteStream` instead of `StringBuffer` can reduce memory usage. `FileWriteStream` uses a fixed size of buffer (can be stored in the stack), while `StringBuffer` needs to store the whole JSON in (heap) memory. It becomes a big difference for big JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You better use

```
fwrite (buffer.GetString(), buffer.GetSize(), 1, wFile);
```

it's safer (in case the buffer is not null-terminated) and faster (no strlen).
Other than that and the lack of error checking in your code, it's fine and should write the JSON to the file NP.

Comment: buffer.GetString() is safe